# Is there any emacs package which can auto refresh the browser when the html file is changed?

Tags: html, emacs, livereload

I found sublime text2 had LiveReload, it can reload the html file in browser when the html file is changed.but I don't use sublime text2 ,I like emacs very much.so I want to know if there is any package similar to Livereload. I really hate pressing f5.

Comment: See also `Auto Reload` plugin for Firefox (or something like this for another browser).

Comment: Auto Reload no longer works since Firefox 57. I created Live Reload as a replacement (Firefox and Chrome): https://github.com/blaise-io/live-reload/#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a least 2 browser-dependent solutions: for [Firefox via MozRepl](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MozRepl) and for [Chrome](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SaveAndReloadBrowser)...

Answer (score 5):

Possibly you might be interested in **Impatient mode**: http://www.50ply.com/blog/2012/08/13/introducing-impatient-mode/

Comment: thanks for your answer. **Impatient mode** is cool. but now I use Auto Reload plugin for firefox. because it is simple and can make things done. if I have time, I will write an package to bring LiveReload to emacs

Answer (score 0):

[skewer-mode](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode) might be what you are looking for.